# iOS: flush all output files

Tags: ios, file

Is there an iOS method to flush all open output files-- so that when the call returns, all pending buffered data is written to persistent storage? I mean this in general terms-- where I don't have access to the specific file handles. I've tried `sync()` from Swift (a POSIX call) but that appears not guaranteed to actually make sure the data hits persistent storage before it returns (see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/functions/sync.html).

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this solves the problem in general, but it's addressing my need. Here's what I'm doing:

```
// Write to file (in my case, this is a log file where I don't have access to the file handle). 
// I'm using logging to a file with SwiftyBeaver. https://github.com/SwiftyBeaver/SwiftyBeaver

DispatchQueue.main.async {
    // Read from the file-- it has the flushed contents. I'm doing:

    do {
        let fileContents = try String(contentsOfFile: path)
    } catch (let error) {
    }
}
```

It looks like files are flushed at the end of the event loop.

Comment: What does this answer have to do with flushing all output files? This is some vague comments with one wrapped to run on the main queue.

Comment: Indeed. This was "working" for a while, but just coincidently I think. I've even tried using `synchronizeFile` with the FileHandle underlying SwiftyBeaver, and that doesn't even seem to have the data contents hit the file before returning. (Reading the file immediately after doesn't necessarily have all contents).